# Run Apache Sling's samples

Tags: java, jackrabbit, jcr, sling

I want to run `simple-demo` from samples but I don't have success. What is its URL and how to reach its content?
The internationalization of `usermanager-ui` also doesn't work, although I installed the `org.apache.sling.i18n` bundle. If someone can give me a guidance I will be very happy.

In general why everything is so poor explained? The motto of Sling is "Bringing Back the Fun!", but in the last few days I didn't have so much fun! It's really painful to try to test or make something. Is there any good tutorial or book about this framework?

P.S. If I run all samples without any problems, I would create a detailed tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

My personal opinion is that simple-demo is not a very current sample, I'd rather recommend hat you look at the slingbucks or espblog samples, as mentioned at http://sling.apache.org/documentation/getting-started/discover-sling-in-15-minutes.html

We might need to cleanup the Sling samples at some point, and concentrate on a few representative ones - I've put that on my way-too-long-list-of-things-to-do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I assume that some of the samples are out of date and that is the problem. Could you please help me to my next question I'm sure it will be a piece of cake for you.

Comment: which next question? It might be better to create a separate stackoverflow question page for that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476554/problems-with-discover-sling-in-15-minutes

Answer (score 1):

Just go through the readme.txt of the respective samples.