# Problems with Discover Sling in 15 minutes

Tags: java, jcr, sling

I have problems with creating a content node with cURL. I execute the following command:

```
curl -u admin:admin -F"sling:resourceType=foo/bar" -F"title=some title" http://localhost:8080/content/mynode
```

But I can't see `http://localhost:8080/content/mynode.html` as there is showed the following problem:

```
Resource dumped by HtmlRendererServlet

Resource path: /content/mynode
Resource metadata: {sling.resolutionPathInfo=.html, sling.resolutionPath=/content/mynode}
Resource type: foo/bar
Resource super type: -

Resource properties

title: some title
sling:resourceType: foo/bar
jcr:createdBy: admin
jcr:created:
```

`http://localhost:8080/content/mynode.json` has following content:

```
{"title":"some title","sling:resourceType":"foo/bar","jcr:createdBy":"admin","jcr:created":"Thu Jul 04 2013 21:24:36 GMT+0300","jcr:primaryType":"sling:Folder"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html output that you get is correct, it's the default Sling HTML rendering.

You probably haven't executed the "Render your content using server-side javascript (ESP)" steps at http://sling.apache.org/documentation/getting-started/discover-sling-in-15-minutes.html which will setup a custom HTML rendering that's more useful.

Comment: Thank you, obviously I haven't completed the tutorial.